# I want to cycle through tab complete results

Tags: linux, autocomplete, csh

I had a bash command that would cycle through my listed results from a tab complete.
Is there something like that for .cshrc?
I want to map the ctrl d keys to cycle through my options
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the `complete-word-fwd` command?

From the manpage:

```
   complete-word-fwd (not bound)
           Replaces the current word with the first word in  the  list  of
           possible completions.  May be repeated to step down through the
           list.  At the end of the list, beeps and reverts to the  incom‐
           plete word.
```

As you can see, it's not bound by default, but you can bind it to `^D` with:

```
bindkey ^D complete-word-fwd
```

There's also `complete-word-back`.

Comment: @user1869582 `man csh` or `man tcsh` (most `csh`s are usually `tcsh` these days).